# How to handle and custom error 401 from Spring boot ldap?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm working in an application that uses Spring secutiry LDAP to authenticate its users, the authentication is working fine, my problem is that if someone try to log in with unauthorized credentials, the application sends immediatly a error 401, and I don't want that, I want to custom some friendly message to show this user, but even in debug I can't find where the application executes de authentication, it even seems that my backend isn't called, how can I custom this exception ?

Here's my configuration on my Security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2147483640)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and()
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}

@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UsrPessoaService usrPessoaService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDetailsContextMapper(usrPessoaService)
                .userDnPatterns("secret")
                .groupSearchBase("secret")
                .contextSource()
                .root("secret")
                .url("secret").port(000);

        System.out.println(auth.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a [WhiteLabel Page](https://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/03/24/spring-boot-convention-based-error-pages)?

For example:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

    if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            return "error-404";
        }
        else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
            return "error-500";
        }
    }
    return "error";
}
```

And an example "error.html" template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Page not found</h1>
<h2>Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for</h2>
<a href="/">Go Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

ADDENDUM:

Since the OP has an Angular front end, these links might also be applicable:

> [Tutorial: Spring Security and Angular](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/).
>
> In this tutorial we show some nice features of Spring Security, Spring
>   Boot and Angular working together to provide a pleasant and secure
>   user experience.
>
> It should be accessible to beginners with Spring and Angular, but
>   there also is plenty of detail that will be of use to experts in
>   either.

See also:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.java

Comment: Hi @paulsm4 ! thanks for helping, I think your suggestion can't work with this application, the reason for this is that the application already has a frontend in angular that calls the backend and expects in return an object with the result or the exception's details with a friendly message as one of its attributes, I may be wrong but I can't see how to work with White Label Pages in this case.